# Understanding a certain class of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, analytic-functions

*Decomposable functions* were introduced in [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlid=rae%2F1272376230), p. 186.

Given a function $f:I\to \mathbb R$, $f$ is said to be *increasing* (resp *decreasing*) at $x$ if, for all $h > 0$ such that $x+h$ belongs to $I$,
$${f(x+h)-f(x)\over h} \geq 0 \quad (resp. \leq 0).$$
$f$ is said to *decomposable* at $x$ if it is either increasing at $x$, or decreasing at $x$, or $x$ is a STRICT extremum of $f$ in $I$.
Finally, $f$ is locally decomposable in $I$ if, for every $x\in I$, there exists an open interval $J\ni x$ of $I$ such that $f$ is decomposable at $x$ in $J$.
Continuous locally decomposable functions provide a nice change of variable theorem for the KH-integral (actually, the aforementioned article deals with locally decomposable functions at all but countably many $x$).

For example, any function which has a Taylor development of order $n > 0$ at each point is locally decomposable.

I was not able to find a characterization of these functions in term of known concepts like "monotonic", "bounded variation", "ACG" etc.
I would be surprised, though, if it were not possible to characterize these functions using known classes of functions.

**So, my question is:** How to characterize nicely these functions?

Comment: Did you try writing the author to learn where this notion arose? If it's original with the author, then I suspect some possibly useful (for your question) results are known that maybe weren't worth including in the paper (or maybe they appear elsewhere, such as in a Masters or Ph.D. thesis by the author or someone else). If it's not original with the author, then the author should be able to tell you where it came from (but it might simply be an idea that someone mentioned to the author verbally at a conference, and not a publication you can look up).

Comment: After some googling, I have found this notion nowhere else, so I believe the author just defined this term locally in the paper for convenience. He uses it at p. 189 in the article. Apparently, his aim was to give a very good practical change of variables of the "second category" (in his terms). I'll try to contact the author though.